# Strange behavior with error messages in Michael Hart Rails Tutorial Chapter 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following the Ruby on Rails tutorial located [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). Everything has been working as expected up to this point, but I just ran into a strange issue that I don't know how to solve. I'm using `Rails 4.2.2`.

I'm up to `Chapter 7: Sign Up` and have implemented all of the code mentioned in this chapter. After implementing all of the code, I've submitted the same data shown in this screenshot from the tutorial, hoping to see the same output on my app:

[image]

However, in my app, I get the following output:

[image]

There are two error messages for the `Password` field, and nothing for the `Confirmation` field. Additionally, the `Confirmation` field is not given the error class like the rest of the fields with errors.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior? It seems like the `has_secure_password` method isn't working correctly. Here's my code:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

**app/views/users/new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you using the same gem versions as the tutorial? `gem 'rails', '4.2.2'` and `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually due to an issue with `has_secure_password`, which is supposed to have a presence validation, but in fact only catches empty (`nil`) passwords. As a result, we are in a bind, because if we leave off the presence validation, it's possible to create users with passwords like `'      '` (six spaces), but if we include it we get double error messages when the password is empty. One possibility would be to manipulate the error messages directly to eliminate duplicates, but luckily the problem goes away in Chapter 9 when we add `allow_nil: true`, so I've added a note to expect double error messages until then.

Answer (score 1):

In `user.rb` you have:

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

You actually don't need the presence validation because the `has_secure_password` method will do this by default.

According to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password):

> The following validations are added automatically:
>
> - Password must be present on creation
> - Password length should be less than or equal to 72 characters
> - Confirmation of password (using a password_confirmation attribute)

Comment: Yes, but the tutorial says "Combining this with a presence validation (Section 6.2.2) to prevent nonblank passwords, this leads to the User model shown in Listing 6.39. (It turns out the has_secure_password method includes a presence validation, but it only applies to new records, which causes problems when updating users.)" and then goes on to show the line `validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }` under `has_secure_password` as I've shown it in my code sample.

Comment: Well that's annoying.. maybe you have a slightly different version of rails or bcrypt and some behavior changed between those versions?

Answer (score 0):

### I am having exactly the same problem, I am looking through the Internet and came to this place hoping to find an answer but I haven't found nothing yet, I even send an email to Rails Tutorial  and this is what Michael replied today:

Hi Sócrates,

Thanks for the note. As seen in the attached screenshot, the [reference app](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition) appears not to have this issue, so there's probably a minor discrepancy between your code and the code in the book. I suggest using the reference app to help track it down.
Best,
Michael

---

So according to Michael it works on his side but I reviewed all the potential files that could be causing the problem and compared them with the reference app and I don't see any problems.

I am going to keep researching on this. I did notice that if I take out the "presence: true, " option from the /app/models/user.rb on the validates :password statement then I only get one "Password can't be blank" error message, but as you mentioned earlier that is supposed to be there because if not then it won't validate for user's updates.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Michael!!